# Autodesk Forge ACC file not translate first version

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have an issue when try get data from `Autodesk Forge` use [Model Derivative](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/).

My problem is I can't get metadata of first version, Example item:

```
urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:BuNmdul6RLqWiQPqMzrQfA?version=1
```

With the item version higher than 1, it working perfect, example :

```
urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:BuNmdul6RLqWiQPqMzrQfA?version=2
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Is it a Revit cloud work-sharing model (version `attributes.extension.type` is `versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel`)?  If yes, that is expected behavior. The first version is an anchor for our service to know where to publish the model.

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang. Yes, it is  versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel

Comment: Ok, then that's explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Revit cloud work-sharing model (version attributes.extension.type is versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel like the below one), the first version is an anchor for our Revit cloud work-sharing service to know where to publish the model. So, there is no derivative id for this version tip as expected.

```json
{
    "type": "versions",
    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g?version=4",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
        "displayName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
        "createTime": "2022-01-28T08:45:55.0000000Z",
        //...
        "lastModifiedTime": "2022-01-28T08:51:44.0000000Z",
        //...
        "versionNumber": 4,
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
        "storageSize": 111297725,
        "fileType": "rvt",
        "extension": {
            "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "schema": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.1.0"
            },
            "data": {
                "modelVersion": 3,
                "isCompositeDesign": true,
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                "compositeParentFile": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
                "projectGuid": "733f13b0-502d-4a1e-6624-b7f22f920290",
                "originalItemUrn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g",
                "modelType": "multiuser",
                "latestEpisodeGuid": "fda2d360-5466-4ev3-b051-0dacbaa509f5",
                "modelGuid": "d1e3bc70-30d0-4e42-86a5-9d00da685TAf",
                "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
                "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
                "revisionDisplayLabel": "4",
                "sourceFileName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
                "conformingStatus": "NONE"
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it make sence now !